# bash: синтаксическая ошибка рядом с неожиданным маркером «fi»

Tags: bash, altlinux

bash: синтаксическая ошибка рядом с неожиданным маркером «fi»
Выдает данную ошибку при выполнении скрипта. Вот сам скрипт полностью:

```
outfile="v.out"

#status=""

for pid in $(ps -axo pid)
do
    file1="/proc/"$pid"/status"
    file2="/proc/"$pid"/sched"
    
    ppid=$(grep -E -s -h "PPid" $file1 | grep -E -s -o "[0-9]+")
    sleepavg=$(grep -E -s -h "avg_atom" $file2 | grep -E -s -o "[0-9.]+")

    if [[ -z $sleepavg ]]
    then 
        sleepavg=0
    fi

    if [[ -n $ppid ]]

    then 
        echo "ProcessID=$pid : Parent_ProcessID=$ppid : Average_Sleeping_Time=$sleepavg"
    fi
done | sort -n -t "=" -k3 > $outfile
```

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю дело в том, что вы добавили пустую строку между операторами if и then, в связи с чем then воспринимается интерпритатором как отдельная конструкция

> ```
> if [[ -n $ppid ]]
>
> then 
>     echo "ProcessID=$pid : Parent_ProcessID=$ppid : Average_Sleeping_Time=$sleepavg"
> fi
> ```

также для проверки своего скрипта можно пользоваться каким-нибудь встроенным плагиной среды разработки например IDEA, или подобным онлайн проверяльщиком https://www.shellcheck.net/